# Developing a Networked Game

Tags: java, networking, client

I am a programmer of intermediate experience and I want to create a networked game. I can not decide what sort of networking "model" I should pick for this game.

By "model" I mean the method by which information should be transferred from server to client and where the processing actually happens. Currently, this is the model that I am thinking of:

- Imagine there are four guys - User, John, Bob, and Server. Server is the guy controlling the game.
- User is sitting at his computer playing the game. He clicks his mouse.
- John is the program on User's computer who detects the mouse click. He doesn't know what it means, but he knows that he's supposed to send it to Bob.
- Bob is at the server's end. He, like John, knows nothing about the click but he knows how communicate with John. He picks up the mouse click and gives it to Server, telling him it came from User.
- Server is the brains. He interprets the mouse click and changes something in the game.
  Every (say) 30 milliseconds, Server renders the game. He knows where User's camera is pointed and so he generates an image which should appear on User's screen.
- Server doesn't know how to send it to User, so he gives it to Bob.
  Bob sends the image to John.
- John displays the image on the screen.

Now, this is a 2 player game so I don't anticipate the server having issues processing all User requests. I would like to hear your feedback on this model. Is it good? If not, what are some alternatives?

Comment: user>john>bob>server==user>program>api>server...is that accurate? What is the relationship between players one and two? Is this a sequential game where they alternately act as the user (chess)? Or are there two simultaneous parties hitting the server? how you've described it, it doesn't sound like a multiplayer system

Comment: @RobotWoods Yes that is correct. The players never communicate with each other. They just send their input to the server who generates the output and returns it to each of the users. It can be compared to a forum like this one: multiple clients send their messages to a server, the server stores them and returns an HTML document to each user containing all of the messages.

Comment: in my opinion, the wording of your question is too imprecise to give a useful answer. the bulk of your question consists of a convoluted example "model" that makes very little sense. the "model" that should be used is heavily reliant on the type of game you are attempting to make, and you've provided no *useful* information. please attempt to revise your question, as i'm eager to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You should absolutely read this entire PDF on how Age of Empires worked.  It's completely relevant, and will help clarify your thinking tremendously:

http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~claypool/courses/4513-B03/slides/BT01.pdf

Comment: Age of Empires was an RTS, and was peer-to-peer.  OP clearly stated he's looking for a client-server game.  These are two completely different things.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft The document describes peer-to-peer networking, but also describes it's pros/cons compared to client/server model.  'It will help clarify your thinking tremendously' is still very much a true statement.

Answer (score -2):

Without having the entire picture, I am thinking that I would build two web services, connected to some DB (most likely).

The first would accept some parameters that were related to the action SOME user performed (click coordinates, time, userID, etc), save those to the DB, and respond with some status detail (success, failure, etc).

The other API would accept time as a parameter, and return (in JSON or XML format) all of the activities that had happened since that time (like in a chat program...here are the messages since you last updated)...or, depending on the game construct, the CUMULATIVE state...for instance, if the game consisted of two teams flipping a tile from red to blue, this API would return the current state of the tile. Then, in the client code, I'd process the response to reflect to that user, the current game state.

Here is some example code. This doesn't auto-update as is, you could set a timeout to periodically poll for new data, or set up some sort of long polling ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)). Oh, and because this was educational, there's no input validation (aside from length):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<title>Game</title>
<style>
html, body {margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;width:100%;}
#board {width:298px;height:298px;border:thin solid #000;position:relative;}
#puck {width:58px; height:58px; display:block; background-image:url('al.png'); background-size:contain; position:absolute; top:120px; left:120px;}
</style>
</head>

<body onload="update();">
<div id="board">
<div id="puck"></div>
</div>
<button onclick="update();">Update</button>
</body>
<script>
var x,y;
document.getElementById('board').addEventListener('click',move);

function move(e){
    a1=((window.XMLHttpRequest)?new XMLHttpRequest():new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"));
    x=(e.clientX-29);
    y=(e.clientY-29);
    a1.abort();
    a1.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (a1.readyState==4&&a1.status==200){
                document.getElementById('puck').style.left = x+'px';
                document.getElementById('puck').style.top= y+'px';
        }
    }
    params='x='+x+'&y='+y;
    a1.open("POST","al_accept.php",true);
    a1.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    a1.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    a1.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    a1.send(params);
}

function update(){
    a2=((window.XMLHttpRequest)?new XMLHttpRequest():new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"));
    a2.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (a2.readyState==4&&a2.status==200){
                res=JSON.parse(a2.responseText)
                x=res.x;
                y=res.y;
                document.getElementById('puck').style.left = x+'px';
                document.getElementById('puck').style.top= y+'px';
        }
    }
    params='x='+x+'&y='+y;
    a2.open("POST","al_respond.php",true);
    a2.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    a2.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    a2.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    a2.send(params);

}
</script>
</html>
```

and you'll see that the `move` function sends data to `al_accept.php` which stores it (here just writing to file since each move over-rides anything prior) and the the `update` function calls `al_respond.php` to retrieve the latest data.

al_accept.php:

```
<?php
$x=(strlen($_REQUEST['x'])>3)?substr($_REQUEST['x'],0,3):$_REQUEST['x'];
$y=(strlen($_REQUEST['y'])>3)?substr($_REQUEST['y'],0,3):$_REQUEST['y'];
$pos=fopen('al.txt','w');
$str='{"x":'.$x.',"y":'.$y.'}';
fwrite($pos,$str);
fclose($pos);
?>
```

al_respond.php:

```
<?php
header('content-type:application/json');
echo file_get_contents('al.txt');
?>
```

If you open this on two machines, you can move the ball on one, and when you update on the other, you'll see the latest position (and vice versa).

Comment: Please explain if you downvote. Are you disagreeing with me attempting to answer what you perceive is an incomplete question? Or disagree with my answer?

Comment: I both disagree with your answer and feel that your answer to an incomplete question will only confuse the asker. Have you ever implemented the system you describe, or know it to be implemented anywhere else? It sounds very complicated, slow, and not explained fully... two "web services" ? an "api" somewhere? maybe i'm just not understanding you...

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes, I did mingle API and web services, but yes, I have built multiple (fast) systems with this construct. One specific example is a canvas based drawing chat program. The first web service accepts an image, a user name, and timestamp. The image is saved to the server, it's file name, with the other parameters are added to a table in the DB. There is another service that users can call (again, using time as the parameter). The DB is queried for all entries more recent that the passed parameter, and those fields are then used in the client app to construct an updated chat

Comment: Also, I do agree with you it could be confusing to propose an alternate solution if the question was clearly asking about some other approach, but since it's a "how would you do it" I think there is room for interpretation

Comment: it seems like you've got more experience with PHP than Java and you're applying core concepts from PHP that simply don't need to be done in Java. With normal socket programming, two of your steps become cumbersome and unnecessary. rather than `client tell server to update, server write update to file / db, client2 ask server for update, server respond with file/db contents` we can simply have `client send update to server, server push update to all clients` because all the clients are already connected to the server itself. `client2` should never be forced to ask the server for an update.

Comment: I downvoted because I felt that this answer was trying to apply web-development techniques to game programming where they **really** don't fit.  This answer would work for very simple, browser-based games; for anything else, this paradigm is absolutely terrible.  Could you imagine if Minecraft required Apache and MySQL instances to run a server!?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I don't know what I don't know, so I am always looking to learn